# TeX4ht: \includegraphics[page=10]{foo.pdf}

Tags: graphics, pdf, tex4ht

I have a long LaTeX document with lots of figures that were included using commands of the form

```
\includegraphics[page=10]{foo.pdf}
```

Everything compiles fine with pdfLaTeX. I planned to convert the document into HTML using TeX4ht, but it seems that TeX4ht does not understand the `page=` attributes in `\includegraphics`.

Are there any easy solutions? Ideally, I would prefer to keep my main Latex source unmodified and just tweak the preamble.

Answer (score 13):

Sorry for being late. Following code is likely to help the Jukka:

```
\makeatletter

\@ifundefined{Configure}
 {\def\Includegraphics[#1]#2{\includegraphics[page={#1}]{#2}}}
 {\def\Includegraphics[#1]#2{\def\GPT@page{#1}\includegraphics{#2}}
  \Configure{graphics*}
   {pdf}
   {\Needs{"
    pdftops -eps -f \GPT@page\space -l \GPT@page\space \Gin@base.pdf \Gin@base-\GPT@page.eps"
    ;
    convert \Gin@base-\GPT@page.eps \Gin@base-\GPT@page.png
    "}%
    \Picture[pict]{\Gin@base-\GPT@page.png}%
   }%
  }%
\makeatother
```

`\Includegraphics[10]{foo.pdf}` should work now both with pdfLaTeX and TeX4ht.

Comment: We are glad to have you here in TeX.SX. A warm welcome to you.

Answer (score 8):

TeX4ht does not use pdfTeX in PDF mode, but dvips instead. However `dvips` can neither read PDF files nor multipage files. Page 10 can be extracted and converted to eps with `epstopdf` of `xpdf`:

```
epstopdf -eps -f 10 -l 10 foo.pdf foo-10.eps
```

Or `ghostscript` can be used, e.g.:

```
gs -dFirstPage=10 -dLastPage=10 -sDEVICE=epswrite -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=foo-10.eps foo.pdf
```

Then in the source:

```
\ifpdf
  \includegraphics[page=10]{foo.pdf}
\else
  \includegraphics{foo-10.eps}
\fi
```

And package `ifpdf` is needed in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
```

Comment: Something along these lines certainly works, but it requires changes in the body of the Latex document. I wonder if I could easily redefine `\includegraphics`; moreover, perhaps I could have Latex run `gs` automatically to when needed?

Comment: It could be done, looking at package `epstopdf` that support external conversion programs for pdfTeX in PDF mode, I would expect several hundred lines of code.